# Android/Java - Issue

Tags: java, android

The code is like this:

```
private DatabaseHelper mOpenHelper;
@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
  mOpenHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());
  System.out.println("done");
  return true;
}
```

Now Eclipse is showing me an <strike>error</strike> warning on the first line of this code "private DatabaseHelper mOpenHelper", that the object mOpenHelper is not used anywhere, whereas in the very next lines of code, I am initializing it. Please tell me why is this happening?

Thanks,
-D

Comment: It is not an error. Eclipse shows it as a warning.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes eclipse is right, You have initialized it and not using it anywhere. It would not complain if you use that mOpenHelper say in a getter method.

Answer (score 1):

The warning doesn't say not be USED anyone, it's saying not being READ anywhere. And it's not. You're declaring it, assigning it, but not reading it.